# Google Chrome mistakenly adds extra .gz at the end of downloads

Tags: google-chrome, download, file-extension

Every time I try to download a `.gz` file, Chrome appends an extra `.gz` at the end of the filename

[image: save as dialog window]

Is this a known bug? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a known Chrome bug : [Issue 1503: Chrome adds extra duplicate extension](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1503).

Reported first in September 05, 2008, it has yet to be fixed (!).

As my understanding goes, Chrome probably mixed up the definitions of several [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a bug, (though I did not realize that it went back to 1503!)

It should be mostly fixed [now](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=49621#c39), although there are still reports of it happening under specific circumstances. However in the latest dev builds (and maybe the latest betas as well) it seems to be working correctly.